# Lightning calendar won't print

Tags: 16.04, printing, lightning

I wish to print a four week range of my Lightning calendar.
The print dialogue screen comes up, and I can enter the title, and all the required details, but the preview pane on the right of the dialogue box is blank, and the 'Print' button is inactive.
What am I getting wrong?

(MacBook Pro 5,5 | Ubuntu 16.04 | Thunderbird 45.7.0)

Update to the problem description:
My Lightning calendar *will* print, but only if I check 'Selected events/tasks' (and then it only prints those that I have selected).
All three layouts (List, Monthly grid, Weekly planner) are printable.

Comment: Did you install printer on your Ubuntu?

Comment: Yes, printing works fine. I can print from Thunderbird with no problem, but not from the Lightning calendar

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you've got enabled your calendar(s) in the left pane of Thunderbird's calendar tab? I.e. clicked the calendar(s) in the list so that they got a thick next to them.

Because what you describe I see with my calendars too, *when* I haven't enabled them in the left calendar list. Of course then also in the right pane where the days are visible, no calendar entries are shown, just the days. That's why (here) the print dialoge shows only an empty preview pane then.

Probably this would be too easy, but sometimes we oversee the little things.

Comment: Good suggestion, but the calendars are all ticked, and the activities I want to print are all visible in the calendar.